# Will a 2.4ghz controller work with a 5.8ghz video transmitter?

Tags: quadcopter, uav, multi-rotor

I’m building an fpv racing drone and I accidentally ordered a 2.4ghz controller and a 5.8ghz video transmitter. Will they work together?

I have 5.8ghz fpv goggles so I assume they will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about the details of your setup, but two devices can communicate to each other only if they use the same frequency band(s) and the same (read: matching) signal encoding.

On the other hand, you can use (as example) 2.4GHz for commands and feedback and 5.8GHz for video transmission.

Comment: Thankyou for your help. That was the answer i was looking for.

Comment: You are welcome. Besides choosing this as the good answer, you might want to upvote it, too (just click on the UP arrow).

Comment: I would upvote it if I had enough reputation. Sorry